# Algebra equation for 3 rank tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-physics, tensors, tensor-rank, tensor-decomposition

Suppose I work in $4$ dimensions. I have an algebraic equation in the following form, which contains a 3 rank tensor $X ^{\alpha \lambda \mu }$
\begin{equation}
X ^{\alpha \lambda \mu }\eta ^{\beta \xi }-X ^{\mu \lambda \alpha
}\eta ^{\beta \xi }-X ^{\beta \lambda \mu }\eta ^{\alpha \xi }+X
^{\beta \lambda \alpha }\eta ^{\mu \xi } =0,
\end{equation}
where $\eta ^{\beta \xi }$ is the Minkowski metric tensor.

What 3 rank tensor $X ^{\alpha \lambda \mu }$ satisfies the  above equation?

Comment: This is a homogeneous linear system with 64 unknowns. You could write the matrix and solve by Gauss method.

Comment: I want the answer in indexed form, for example, symmetric or antisymmetric, etc

Comment: A computed solution would give you a starting point: the dimension of the solution space and a basis of this space.